# slider shows a single image

Tags: javascript, css

I have three images which I want to be in a slide show using javascript, the problem is that it shows the first image only and blank for the other two. What can the problem be?

I have searched the internet for similar solutions but they do not work with my situation.

```
<div class="owl-init slider-main owl-carousel" data-items="1" data-nav="true" data-dots="false">
    <div class="item-slide slide1">
        <img src="images/banners/slide2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item-slide slide1">
        <img src="images/banners/slide1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item-slide slide1">
        <img src="images/banners/slide3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ============== main slidesow .end // ============= -->
<!-- ============== slider auto scroll js ============= -->

<script>

      let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.item-slide'),
      current=0;
     //clear all images
      function reset(){
        for(let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++){
          sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
      //init slider
      function startSlide(){
         reset(); 
        sliderImages[current].style.display = 'block';
        if(current < sliderImages.length - 1){
          current++;
          //document.write(current)
        }
        else{
              current = 0;
              //document.write(current)
           }
           //document.write(sliderImages.length);
                 setTimeout("startSlide()",2000);

      }
startSlide();       
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the image URL that you have given. It's working for me

```html
<div class="owl-init slider-main owl-carousel" data-items="1" data-nav="true" data-dots="false">
    <div class="item-slide slide1">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item-slide slide1">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item-slide slide1">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ============== main slidesow .end // ============= -->
<!-- ============== slider auto scroll js ============= -->

<script>

      let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.item-slide'),
      current=0;
     //clear all images
      function reset(){
        for(let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++){
          sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
      //init slider
      function startSlide(){
         reset(); 
        sliderImages[current].style.display = 'block';
        if(current < sliderImages.length - 1){
          current++;
          //document.write(current)
        }
        else{
              current = 0;
              //document.write(current)
           }
           //document.write(sliderImages.length);
                 setTimeout("startSlide()",2000);

      }
startSlide();       
   </script>
```